# How can I check if doc in mongodb past a day?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, api

I have an API that gives me a token, that EXPIRES after 24hours.

I want to save it to my tokens collection, and check every time if it past a day, if so generate a new one.

I've installed moment package if its helps.

any suggestions?

My code:

```
  try {
    

    const getTheToken = await TokenModel.findOne({
      name: 'theOPToken',
    });

    // const currentTime = Date.now();
    // const previousTime = getTheToken.lastUpdate;
    // const oneDay = 86400000; // 24 hours in milliseconds

    if (currentTime + oneDay > previousTime) {

//! if so go and generate a new one . 

//! and
      await TokenModel.findOneAndUpdate(
        {
          name: 'theOPToken',
        },
        {
          $set: {
            accessToken: token,
            lastUpdate: Date.now(),
          },
        }
      );

}
```

Comment: What exactly is the error or unexpected result you get with the code provided? (With thee commented code uncommented)

Comment: Should that be `currentTime > previousTime + oneDay`?

Comment: sorry @OluwafemiSule you right . it was just one of my attempts .

Comment: @mousetail , it just return false every time